# Pivot multiple rows to columns in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm looking for a smooth way to transpose a large set of rows into columns without having to mention each row distinct value in ad hoc `CASE WHEN` statements, given that the number of distinct values I want to convert into columns is certainly not small.

To sum it up, I have a table looking like the one below:

```
seller product
a      1
b      1
b      2
a      6
c      4
d      7
a      4
b      7
d      1
```

My goal is to get a single column representing each seller which would store a list of the products each one has available. Hence, out of the example provided the output I'm trying to achieve would look like this:

```
a      b     c     d
1      1     4     7
6      2           1
4      7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` to add a sequence number and then aggregate by that:

```
select max(case when seller = 'a' then product end) as a,
       max(case when seller = 'b' then product end) as b,
       max(case when seller = 'c' then product end) as c,
       max(case when seller = 'd' then product end) as d       
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by seller order by product) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Note:  This orders by the product, so the results are not exactly in the order specified in your query.  There is no "original" ordering in the table, because SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  You can use another column or expression for the `order by` if you have a preferred ordering.

Comment: Actually in the dataset I'm working in, the number of distinct sellers is large enough that I would like to find a way to avoid having to mention each single one in the query. Is it feasible?

Comment: @teogj . . . I would recommend generating the code in a spreadsheet.